# stop or pause counting user's session duration depending on Visibility API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using **userId** feature on google analytics to track users event.

I want stop or pause user's lifetime (or maybe it is called session duration time), depending on:

```
(<any>document).addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
 if ((<any>document).hidden) {
// sendEvent : hidden
// stop or pause counting user's session
}
 else {
//sendEvent : visible
// sendEvent : continue lifetime time counting on same session
}
}
```

To resume I don't want count time user is on site if user is hidding the page, i want consider it as he's is not on site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a hit to Google Analytics with session control parameter set to `end`. I suppose detecting a document 'blur' event and sending a relevant hit to analytics would work for you.
Here is the doc on session control https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#sc

Comment: you pointing me on v1 you confirm it works ? it seems this is what I need but i tried `(<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview', {'sessionControl': 'end'});` it doesn't work, need I send event or have you example how send this parameter in my last event in document.blur

Comment: Just checked this once again and the session is reset for the exactly next hit after ga('send', 'pageview', {'sessionControl': 'end'});

Comment: it seems not, event is sent correctly, but in "real  time view" i always can see 1 visitor is on page (event after 2/3mn)

Comment: that's ok since real time doesn't report sessions but only visitors in 30 minutes timeframe.
Check this with a test visit with some specified utm labels to detect if a session is closed with `sc=end` and then reset with another hit with sources or landing pages report

Comment: Here is what I got in a test with a single user and ga('send', 'pageview', {'sessionControl': 'end'}); http://nimb.ws/Ws7693